# SQLfluff parsing violation when aliasing column from generate_series()

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlfluff

On using sqlfluff to lint postgreSQL query, ended up in a parsing violation while attempting to set alias for column generated via `generate_series()`. Query works fine though.

Not sure of how to set alias for columns generated via `generate_series()`,

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW dummy AS
WITH base_times AS (
    SELECT
        (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'america/los_angeles' + INTERVAL '2 hours')::date AS base_start,
        (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'america/los_angeles' + INTERVAL '2 hours' - INTERVAL '12 weeks' + INTERVAL '1 day')::date AS base_end,
        (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'america/los_angeles' + INTERVAL '2 hours' - INTERVAL '1 day')::date AS base_next_start
),
bucket AS (
    SELECT (generate_series(
        time_bucket('7 days', base_end, base_start)::date,
        time_bucket('7 days', base_next_start, base_start)::date,
        INTERVAL '7 days'
    ) + INTERVAL '6 days')::date AS end
    FROM base_times
) select * from bucket;
```

Error:

```
[L: 14, P:  1]      |                                                            whitespace:  '    '
[L: 14, P:  5]      |                                                            [META] dedent:
[L: 14, P:  5]      |                                                            end_bracket:  ')'
[L: 14, P:  6]      |                                                    whitespace:  ' '
[L: 14, P:  7]      |                                                    binary_operator:  '+'
[L: 14, P:  8]      |                                                    whitespace:  ' '
[L: 14, P:  9]      |                                                    datetime_literal:
[L: 14, P:  9]      |                                                        datetime_type_identifier:
[L: 14, P:  9]      |                                                            keyword:  'INTERVAL'
[L: 14, P: 17]      |                                                        whitespace:  ' '
[L: 14, P: 18]      |                                                        quoted_literal:  "'6 days'"
[L: 14, P: 26]      |                                                [META] dedent:
[L: 14, P: 26]      |                                                end_bracket:  ')'
[L: 14, P: 27]      |                                            casting_operator:  '::'
[L: 14, P: 29]      |                                            data_type:
[L: 14, P: 29]      |                                                datetime_type_identifier:
[L: 14, P: 29]      |                                                    keyword:  'date'
[L: 14, P: 33]      |                                [META] dedent:
[L: 14, P: 33]      |                                whitespace:                   ' '
[L: 14, P: 34]      |                                unparsable:                   !! Expected: 'Nothing here.'
[L: 14, P: 34]      |                                    word:                     'AS'
[L: 14, P: 36]      |                                    whitespace:               ' '
[L: 14, P: 37]      |                                    word:                     'end'
[L: 14, P: 40]      |                            newline:                          '\n'

==== parsing violations ====
L:  14 | P:  34 |  PRS | Line 14, Position 34: Found unparsable section: 'AS end'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list of [PostgreSQL Key Words](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html) defines `end` as **reserved**.

> SQL distinguishes between reserved and non-reserved key words. According to the standard, reserved key words are the only real key words; they are never allowed as identifiers

So I suspect the real cause of the problem is the illegal column name `end` and you should quote it or change.

But you are right e.g. this query works perfect in 14.10

```
select 1 as end
```

Comment: Ahh! literally spent a day going through the docs to fix this. Thanks!